# Understand Maven Repository with respect to Artifactory like Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am trying to set up CI & CD in a project I am working for my company. I am using Maven as the build tool and Nexus Repository for storing the artifacts. I want to know the actual concept for setting up maven with nexus so that build time is fast and maven doesn't always connect to central maven repository on the internet for downloading the dependencies. I came across the proxy repository concept from nexus documentation and implemented the same. So now, my nexus maven central proxy repository acts as the central repository for maven and the ~/.m2 as its local repository. Is there any way or the right concept to make the nexus central proxy repository as maven's local repository so that my builds will be faster and no storage will be occupied in the host server where maven is running?

Comment: No, you always need local cache (even if ephemeral). If your repository proxy(Nexus) is on same (company) network, then download speed shouldn't be problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can delete the local repository on the CI server regularly if you get into disk space trouble.